# How to increase Atomikos default jta timeout based on the thread during Spring retry

Tags: transactions, jta, spring-retry, atomikos

I am using Spring boot application with Atomikos transactions. I have configured default time out as 10000ms which is 10sec in the transactions properties.

transactions .properties

```
com.atomikos.icatch.default_jta_timeout=10000
com.atomikos.icatch.threaded_2pc=true
com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout=300000
com.atomikos.icatch.max_actives=1000
```

Because of the Jta timeout, if any user transaction takes more than 10 sec, then that particular thread  transaction will get timeout and roll back.

Atomikos Logs for user transaction taking more than specified threshold time.

```
[Atomikos:3] [] [] [] [] c.a.icatch.imp.ActiveStateHandler - Transaction InsightJTA160327483422900028 has timed out - rolling back...
```

Here my question is, I am using Spring retry for specific functions. For example if any Database exception or MQ exception occurs then I will do the retry for the same function 3 times with the interval  of 30sec as like below,

```
            retryTemplate.execute(context -> {
                log.info("Processing request...");   // Time interval 30 sec, max attempts 3  
                saveUserOperation(user);             // if any exception, current thread time out,      
                dropMessageToMQ(message);            // should be increased to 120S(120000ms) 
            });
```

Here if saveUserOperation or dropMessageToMQ throw any exceptions then Spring retry will start after 30 sec, but here I have configured default JTA time is 10 sec so before retry start, transaction got timeout. I just want to know, is there any possibility to increase the timeout for the current thread when the retry happen.

I can increase the default timeout but it will applicable for all threads, I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try `setTransactionTimeout` on the JTA `UserTransaction` object.

Or use Spring's `@Transactional` with a timeout: [refer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html).